# File System Searches and Files Moves with Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a bit of a random task I have created for myself. I basically have a git repo in which there is a file structure and within a specific folder, I have several subfolders and nested in those folders are 3 config folders which have the same name. I am trying to create a powershell script thatll comb through the "Target Folder", copy the "Folder 1", "Folder 2", and "Folder 3", but only copy the contents of the 3 "Config Folder"s, maintaining that file structure, but only copying whats needed. Ideally, after that process, id love to rename these files with part of the name of the folder name to help differentiate. I do have plans to integrate a second part of the script to parse through those config files and export to an excel doc, but not sure how much I need that at the moment. The intended output is below, played around with a few misc file structure commands, but have not found much to help me achieve the below result.

File Structure:

- Repo

  - TARGET FOLDER

    - DATA

      - FOLDER1

        - CONFIGFOLDER
        - MISC
      - FOLDER2

        - CONFIGFOLDER
        - MISC
      - FOLDER3

        - CONFIGFOLDER
        - ETC

Hoping to end up with

- Export Folder

  - TARGET FOLDER

    - FOLDER1

      - CONFIGFOLDER

        - List of files with "FOLDER1_ogfilename.yaml"
    - FOLDER2

      - CONFIGFOLDER

        - List of files with "FOLDER2_ogfilename.yaml"
    - FOLDER3

      - CONFIGFOLDER

        - List of files with "FOLDER3_ogfilename.yaml"

I have created the following item to attempt this, and it copies the file structure, but it creates a folder for each .yaml file within that folder.

```
$sourceDir = "C:\Users\hhh\appdev\hhh\data\environments"
$targetDir = "C:\Users\hhh\appdev\targetfolder"

Get-ChildItem $sourceDir -Recurse | % {
   $dest = $targetDir + $_.FullName.SubString($sourceDir.Length)

   If (!($dest.Contains('research,qa,production,global')) -and !(Test-Path $dest))
   {
        mkdir $dest
   }

   Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $dest -Force
}
```

Comment: Your `.Contains()` call looks for verbatim substring `research,qa,production,global` in full in your file path. is that the intent? Did you mean `$dest -match 'research|qa|production|global'`, i.e to look for any one of those words to be present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are issues with your code.

- you need to add switch `-File` to the Get-ChildItem cmdlet to have it look for files, not the directories inside $sourceDir
- use `Join-Path` to construct your destination folder path. By adding the two strings together like you do, you will be missing a backslash
- use the files `DirectoryName` property instead of its `FullName` when taking the substring from it, otherwise the $dest variable will also include the file name (creating folders for every file)
- apparently you wish to not copy files from folders having certain keywords in their path name, so you need to put the copy command inside the test, not below it

Try:

```
$sourceDir = "C:\Users\hhh\appdev\hhh\data\environments"
$targetDir = "C:\Users\hhh\appdev\targetfolder"

Get-ChildItem $sourceDir -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    # use the files DirectoryName, not the FullName property, otherwise the path will include the file name as well
    $dest = Join-Path -Path $targetDir -ChildPath $_.DirectoryName.SubString($sourceDir.Length)
    # exclude paths containing these words
    if ($dest -notmatch 'research|qa|production|global') {
        # create the new folder if it does not already exist
        $null = New-Item -Path $dest -ItemType Directory -Force
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry! I was in an accident and was unable to respond until now. This works to copy the `'research|qa|production|global'` folders when I change `-notmatch` to `-match`, but it still copies all of the subfolders in the original `'research|qa|production|global'` folders. Is there a way I can change this script to pull .yaml files out of the `connections` subfolder and have them be the only thing that is dumped to the destination `'research|qa|production|global'` folders?

Comment: @BenS There is no `connections` folder in your example tree, nor did you mention that in your question.. If you want just a certain file type, simply add `-Filter '*.yaml'` to the Get-ChildItem command

Comment: Per the posting rules I submitted another question with the specifics. I selected your question as my answer as it got me the closest to my outcome, thanks!!!